# Changing Win 8.1 Pro Store App Installation Folder

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-app, mklink

I have a Dell Venue 8 Pro tablet with Windows 8.1.  The c:\ is very limited capacity at only 24GB.  With the OS only on the c:\ I just have 8.6GB of free space.  So I have added a 64gb SSD to the machine and want to install all my apps on it and not the C Drive.  I know the apps get installed in c:\Program Files\WindowsApps folder so I have ROBOCOPY'd all the files to d:\Program Files\WindowsApps and created a symbolic link using mklink.  It seems that new apps are install correctly now on d:\ however the existing apps fail to open. What is the Microsoft's solution to making this happen seamlessly?

Comment: there is no official MS way to move the install folder.

Comment: You could try making a hard link from the original folder to the new location - [Source](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/nifty-way-safely-move-folders-or-programs-another-drive-or-partition-windows-7.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Symbolic Link isn't working and you cannot truly make Hard Links to other volumes, try mounting the SSD in as the `c:\Program Files\WindowsApps` folder.  You can do this by going into Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Disk Management. Once there, modify the drive mount settings for your SSD to specify a blank folder instead of a drive letter (make sure the folder `c:\Program Files\WindowsApps` exists and is empty first).

This essentially creates a pseudo-hard link to your SSD that *should* help resolve your problems.

However, since Microsoft has no official means of moving App storage, I cannot garuantee that this will work correctly either.